# Combine two bash find commands

Tags: bash

I have two similar `find` commands that I basically have the same code for both once the while loop begins. I want to combine them so I only need one `find` to search through files and directories, instead of one to search directories and one to search files. Here are the two that I want to combine into one line:

```
find "$ORIG_DIR" -name "*" -type d | while read dname

find "$ORIG_DIR" -name "*" -type f | while read fname
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide multiple `-type` options with `-o`, such as `-type d -o -type f` in a single command.

```
find "$ORIG_DIR" -name "*" -type d -o -name "*" -type f | while read file
```

<sup>`-o` matches all parameters, so the `-name` is provided twice in the above command.</sup>

Comment: @patrix Rewritten, now it doesn't re-traverse, and works :)

Comment: For the `while` at the end, will this work: `while read dname; fname; do` work?

Comment: `while read fame; do ... done`. Might be a good idea to google for "Shell Scripting Primer"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the test command to see whether it is a file or a folder:

```
find "$ORIG_DIR" | while read thing; do
    if [[ -d "$thing" ]]; then
        # do whatever you want to do with the directory
    fi
    if [[ -f "$thing" ]]; then
        # do whatever you want to do with the file
    fi
done
```